# Twitter Typeahead - Prefetch

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I am using the twitter typeahead and I am calling an api to give me a list of names. Unfortunately, it does not work. ANy helps is appreciated.

```
  var employees = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
prefetch: {
  url: 'http://private-9e8a6-directory4.apiary-mock.com/employees',
  ttl: 0
}
```

});

```
  $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
name: 'employees',
source: employees,
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable name on which you want to perform search. For example in your case I am using name to fetch records.

```
{  
    "id": "1",  
    "name": "Sue",  
    "jobTitle": "Programmer",  
    "location": "Houston",
    "email":"sue@email.com",
    "phoneNumber":"1234567890"
}
```

I am using the "name" data-member.

```
var employees = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: 'http://private-9e8a6-directory4.apiary-mock.com/employees'
  });
```

Also set display to "name"

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'employees',
    source: employees,
    display: 'name'
});
```